# How to 'link' a select attribute and a radio input in html?

Tags: jquery, html, select, radio-button

I would Like to know how do I kind of link a html select attribute and a radio-button input, something like this:

```
<body>
   <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="opt1">
   <label for="opt1">Opcao 1</label>

   <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="opt2">
   <label for="opt2">Opcao 2</label>

   <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="opt3">
   <label for="opt3">Opcao 3</label>

   <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="opt4">
   <label for="opt4">Opcao 4</label>

   <select id="radioselector">
       <option><label for="opt1">Option 1</label></option>
       <option><label for="opt2">Option 2</label></option>
       <option><label for="opt3">Option 3</label></option>
       <option><label for="opt4">Option 4</label></option>
   </select>
```

The thing is, I want to when I select the radio button, the select correspondent get selected too, and vice-versa. I'm trying to make it happen with jquery but, despites my efforts, I'm getting nothing... I'm noob at webprogramming, specialy at jquery.

If you guys could give me a hand, that would be great! Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is the actual purpose for doing this?  Have you made any attempt to actually do this? If so, can you show your code for this and explain the problem you are having with the code?

Comment: Yes, I really tried making it, but, as I stated, I'm new at web development... The purpose of it, is to give the end user the oportunity of choosing from a select or from a radio input with a image label, with it, we target different types of users, that is, people who is more 'visual', opt to choose the image input, while, the more 'straight' people, will go by the select option. I think it is some kind of User Experience topic, I think... Thanks for the interest!

Comment: OK that makes sense, but why do you actually need to sets of form inputs?  You could just as easily place an onclick event on an `<img>` to do the same thing (change the selected option) without having the confusion of multiple inputs POSTing to your receiving script, and then having to do things like verifying the selected value from the radio input matches the selected value from the select.  In other words, consider simplifying your approach.  One data point should match to one input, not two.

Comment: You're right! I am going to do that! Using what, today, I learned from you guys! Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a change-event handler to the radio group and the select element:

```
var $radioGroup = $('input:radio[name=grp1]'),
    $select = $("#radioselector");

$radioGroup.change(function() {
    $select.val($radioGroup.filter(':checked').val());
});

$select.change(function() {
    $radioGroup.filter('[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Note: With the code above, the "id" attributes on the radio buttons are not needed (except for the labels to reference), but you really should have "value" attributes on the radio buttons to have valid HTML. You should also remove the label elements from inside the option elements.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mm2mu/2/)

Edit: I updated the jsfiddle to make it clear that the code above should be placed inside a document-ready handler.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very good and it helped me a lot! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle that has a solution

Your js should look something like this.

```
$("input[name='grp1']").click(function() {
    $("#radioselector")[0].value = this.value;
});

$("#radioselector").click(function() {
    $("#" + this.value).click();
});
```

And you need to add value attributes to your radio buttons and select options.

http://jsfiddle.net/4u6p4/

Comment: for completeness sake I will choose the John answer, but still, your answer is more than correct and teached me a different way of having the work done, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wDv2k/1/)

```
<script>
    function setSelect(i){
          $('select').val(i);
        }
</script>
    <select autocomplete="off">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <a href="#" onClick="setSelect(0);">Set Select to 0</a><br>
    <a href="#" onClick="setSelect(1);">Set Select to 1</a><br>
    <a href="#" onClick="setSelect(2);">Set Select to 2</a>
```

You need to custom it :)

Comment: Despite its not exactly what I was looking for, still is good solution for a variation of the same problem! Thanks!

Comment: Just I show way to you.And i'm haven't enough time for custom codes!```You need to custom it :)```

Comment: My source is too short ```function setSelect(i){$('select').val(i);}`` :)